# CSV to JSON conversion based on a key

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to convert a `CSV` file to `JSON`.

My input file is something like this:

```
1,data_1,value_1
1,data_2,value_2
1,data_3,value_3
2,data_1,value_1
2,data_4,value_4
2,data_5,value_5
```

My expected output is:

```json
[
 {
   "unique_code": "1",
   "data_1": "value_1",
   "data_2": "value_2",
   "data_3": "value_3"
 },
 {
   "unique_code": "2",
   "data_1": "value_1",
   "data_4": "value_4",
   "data_5": "value_5"
 }
]
```

I need to append the values from columns 2 and 3 along with column 1 as key/value pairs until my first column sequence changes. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: this could do the trick:

```
import csv

with open("test.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")

    index = {}

    for row in spamreader:
        if row[0] not in index.keys():
            index[row[0]] = {}

        index[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]

    # print pre list
    print(index)

    # convert the list to an array
    #
    result = [dict([("unique_code", k)] + list(index[k].items())) for k in index.keys()]
    print(result)
```

Long answer:

taking the basic example from the [python csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

import csv

```
with open("test.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
```

I create an "index" data structure so I can update each time I have a row with the same index number and each time I read a row of the csv I populate the index dictionary with the format

`{index (row[0]): {row[1]: row[2]}}`

`{1: {"data_1": "value_1"}}`

```
    index = {}

    for row in spamreader:
        if row[0] not in index.keys():
            index[row[0]] = {}

        index[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]
```

NOTE: you can use the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) library so you can omit the `if` sentence that checks if the value of an index number is empty

After that you get a dictionary with this format:

```
{ '1': {
        'data_1': 'value_1',
        'data_2': 'value_2'
       }
}
```

since you need to make it more like a List we can use a list expression that creates a dict with a merge of {'unique_code', '1'} and {'data_1: 'value_1'...}:

```
result = [dict([("unique_code", k)] + list(index[k].items())) for k in index.keys()]
```

### Bonus: saving into a text file:

I think the most easy way to save it preserving the structure could be using the [python json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
    # saving into JSON don't forget to add your <import json> at the top
    with open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
        json.dump(result, out_file, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing a detailed solution. Can I write the result array into a txt file?

Comment: I don know in which structure you can save but the most simple way is to use the json library and dump it as a text, let me update my answer adding that